# How to update user meta field after a action is completed

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I tried to update user meta field after the checkout payment is successful. I tried keeping the following code in thankyou.php

```
update_user_meta($user->ID, '_uw_balance', $updated_balance);
```

Actually i'm using a wallet plugin called "User Wallet Credit System" and using the user wallet balance to get deducted in the total order amount. I'm able to deduct the wallet amount in order total but unable to update the wallet after the successful payment.

I'm using woocommerce for the checkout and everything. I need to how should i update the wallet amount after the transaction is processed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `woocommerce_thankyou` being called after successful checkout.
you can play with order id,

```
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'update_e_wallet', 11, 1);
function update_e_wallet($order_id) {
    //do something...
}
```

also you can get user by order id

```
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
$user_id = $order->user_id;
```

Comment: Thank you. Worked like a charm